# clamav "killed" with no explanation

Tags: clamav, debian-buster

On a Debian 10 server I have this problem with clamav:

```
root@vps:~# clamscan -r -v --stdout /
Killed
```

You see I use the verbose flag but that does not give me any information.  In years of using clam I have not had this problem.  I know it's not a database problem:

```
root@vps:~# freshclam
Sun Mar  1 00:18:39 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Sun Mar  1 00:18:39 2020
Sun Mar  1 00:18:39 2020 -> daily.cvd database is up to date (version: 25737, sigs: 2201376, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Sun Mar  1 00:18:39 2020 -> main.cvd database is up to date (version: 59, sigs: 4564902, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Sun Mar  1 00:18:39 2020 -> bytecode.cvd database is up to date (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
```

Please suggest steps to test.

EDIT: This is an OpenVZ VPS with 512MB RAM.

EDIT:  `strace` shows `killed by SIGKILL` but that doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Try asking on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ClamAV usually requires fair amount of RAM to execute. Check with `dmesg`, probably it's `oom_killer` who killed it.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in some of the other comments, the likely culprit is `oom_killer` or `oom_reaper`. You can check for this by tailing `/var/log/messages` while running `clamscan`.  Ex:

```
# Kick this off in a console and keep an eye on it
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages

# Run this in a separate console
sudo clamscan /etc/
```

In my case, `clamscan` died after a few seconds, and messages such as the following appeared within `/var/log/messages`:

```
kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope,task=clamscan,pid=1520,uid=0
kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 1520 (clamscan) total-vm:836952kB, anon-rss:540640kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:1248kB oom_score_adj:0
kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 1520 (clamscan), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

So, if you observe the same thing, then you should try allocating more resources (ie: memory) to the machine instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/etc/ld.preload.so` has *no* entries, any entry in that file would be suspicious. Verify modified timestamps on all files in `/etc`.

Try `strace freshclam` to gather more information.

Comment: /etc/ld.preload.so does not exist.  Anyway you are going in a different direction than my question.  If strace output is intelligible to you then all I have to say brother is 001011010001010.  I tried that before and it does not show me anything that indicates an error in words.

Comment: In case clamav is simply killed/dies it is suspicious. I'm not aware of any other useful debug information in this case other than the `strace` output which shows calls at syscall level.

Comment: As you updated the question above it seems that in your environment there is something that sends a `SIGKILL` to `clamav`. Behaviour like that I've so far only seen on compromised systems. Typically in combination with some mechanism to shade that activities (e.g. preloaded libraries in /etc/ld.preload.so) which hide e.g processes in `ps` outputs, files in directory listings, ....

Comment: It is a fresh install so that is unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: It might as well be an OOM kill or something different. `SIGKILL` is pretty clear. Within your provided details there is no information on why it was issued to the clamav process.

Comment: I agree.  That's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

its an old thread but mot likely ppl will come to it. this happens because of not having enough memory on system. use command free -m and check if you have swap file enabled, if not enable it and give it min 2 GB and try again and error will disappear.